# @ModelAttribute Display Value Methods (for JSP Variables) Outside of Controller

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

In our Controllers we have methods for populating some Display Values used by the JSP. Example: the list of US States:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/myURL")
public class MyController {

    //...

    // A US State ModelAttribute populator used by JSP
    @ModelAttribute("us_states")
    public TreeMap<String,String> getStateDisplayValues()
    {
        // ... Code to populate US states for a dropdown
    }

}
```

In JSP:

```
<form:select path="state">
  <form:options items="${us_states}" />
</form:select>
```

**But a concern came up that the Controller shouldn't have this method, it should go in a different place, like the Model.** Maybe we are violating some MVC principle by defining these methods in the Controller.

However when I tried moving these @ModelAttribute methods to my Model object, the JSP stopped working. What is the proper place to put these JSP variables? Do I just create Model fields on top of my "regular" model to support them?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://developer.ucsd.edu/develop/user-interface/building-a-form/form-binding-with-collections.html

Answer (score 1):

[@ModelAttribute only supported for controller classes with @RequestMapping methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ModelAttribute.html), so you can't move to your Model object.

us_states not a JSP variables, its a global variable within the scope of controller associated to [Model](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html) object while passing to JSP.

I prefer using @ModelAttribute if there is one time static data has to load from database(like states), instead of calling every time or otherwise, you can put the states in Enum and pass it to JSP.